# How to find closest value of each value in a column in a DataFrame to another column in other DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes which I read from two csv files.

airportDF 150kb 7000 records

```
iata_code   latitude    longitude
AAA -17.352606  -145.509956
AAB -26.69317   141.0478
AAC 31.07333    33.83583
```

userDF ~75MB ~1million records

```
uuid    geoip_latitude  geoip_longitude
DDEFEBEA-98ED-49EB-A4E7-9D7BFDB7AA0B    -37.8333015441895   145.050003051758
DAEF2221-14BE-467B-894A-F101CDCC38E4    52.5167007446289    4.66669988632202
31971B3E-2F80-4F8D-86BA-1F2077DF36A2    35.685001373291 139.751403808594
```

I want to find which airport is nearest to the user based upon the geo-distance.

The output should have two columns **UUID and corresponding iata_code**

I have haversine utility function for calculating the geo-distance

```
def distance(
      startLon: Double,
      startLat: Double,
      endLon: Double,
      endLat: Double,
      R: Double
  ): Double = {
    val dLat = math.toRadians(endLat - startLat)
    val dLon = math.toRadians(endLon - startLon)
    val lat1 = math.toRadians(startLat)
    val lat2 = math.toRadians(endLat)

    val a =
      math.sin(dLat / 2) * math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        math.sin(dLon / 2) * math.sin(dLon / 2) * math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2)
    val c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))

    R * c
  }
```

**EDIT:**

```
userDF
 |-- uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geoip_latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- geoip_longitude: double (nullable = true)

airportDF
 |-- iata_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)


transformations(spark, userDF, airportDF).show()

def transformations(spark: SparkSession, userDF: DataFrame, airportDF: DataFrame) = {
    val airports = broadcastDF(spark, airportDF)
    userDF.transform(findNearestAirport(spark, airports.value))
  }

  def broadcastDF(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame) = {
    spark.sparkContext.broadcast(df.collect())
  }

  def findNearestAirport(spark: SparkSession, airports: Array[Row])(
    userDF: DataFrame
  ): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._

    var distance = Double.MaxValue
    var minDistance = Double.MaxValue
    var nearestAirportID = ""

    userDF.flatMap { user =>
      airports.foreach { airport =>
        distance = Haversine.distance(
          user.getAs[Double]("geoip_longitude"),
          user.getAs[Double]("geoip_latitude"),
          airport.getAs[Double]("longitude"),
          airport.getAs[Double]("latitude")
        )
        if (minDistance > distance) {
          minDistance = distance
          nearestAirportID = airport.getAs[String]("iata_code")
        }
      }
      println(s"User ${user.getAs[String]("uuid")} is closest to airport $nearestAirportID")
      Seq((user.getAs[String]("uuid"), nearestAirportID))
    }.toDF("uuid", "iata_code")
  }
```

So I finished the code but have a few questions.

1. I used DF.transform function instead of UDF. Is it better or the same?
2. Most/all broadcast examples on the internet were with map-like structure/json/case class. I just broadcasted with the DF as it is. is there any advantage/disadvantage of one over another.
3. Any way I can improve the code?
4. Is this a good enough scalable solution? I choose to use spark myself as if the data is streaming it can also deal with it easily. What could have been some other scalable options, (in Scala) without using a streaming/batch engine like Spark, considering there could be hundreds or thousands of events per second?

Comment: do you want to achieve this using the dataframe api or are you open to use the dataset api?

Comment: I can use Dataset as well.

Comment: can you please remove the image and add the data in text? So that it will be easy if anyone wants to copy it quickly and test it out.

Comment: @koiralo sure, done!

Comment: just thinking out loud here, but could you collect the airport data as a map and broadcast it and compute the distance between user and all airports on a flatMap operation?

Comment: that's what I wrote in the second question. Is that an efficient way to do in realtime? Also, what are the other options?
the data is available as csv file.

Answer (score 0):

1. first, merge the uuid, lat/long columns into a tuple using `struct`

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct
   airportDF.withColumn("uuid_lat_long_struct", struct(airportDF("uuid"),airportDF("geoip_lat"), airportDF("geoip_long"))
   ```
2. use `collect_set` to collapse each row from airportDF to an array/list and create a new `airportFlattenedDF` dataframe. for e.g.

   ```
   airportDF.groupBy('uuid').agg(collect_list('uuid_lat_long_struct'))
   ```
3. use this airportDF to `collect()` on the driver side into an array of tuples and then `broadcast` to all the executor nodes.
4. write a lambda or UDF to take each record of userDF and compare it to each element in the array of and pick the element with the smallest distance and return the UUID from the `airportFlattenedDF`
5. Another optimization, you can do is to use `flat-earth` formula which will reduce the number of trigonometric functions, since you care only about the relative distance.

Comment: I thinik there are a few mistakes/misunderstandings in your answer. 
1) is syntactic. 2) why groupby when it cant be grouped. all uuids are unique?
3) how will it join when there's no field/predicate to join on?

Comment: 1) not sure what you are referring to. this one concatenates 2 columns using a function called `struct`. this is needed as we required both lat/long to perform calculation. 2) groupby is done so we can `pivot`, which is done using `collect_list`. this gives you the array to compare against each element(row) of airport.3) yes, I see it has no col to join - I meant `broadcast variable`. will correct the option HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated and posted some other questions could u answer pls. 
Also, I didn't merged using struct because the schema was nested and difficult to read, it worked fine without it. And didn't use both lambda and UDF. 
The flat-earth idea sounds really good, I'll look at it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the function to calculate the distance, I would use the dataset API and then do a flatMap

```
case class User(id: String, lat: Double, longitude: Double)
case class Airport(id: String, lat: Double, longitude: Double)

val users = usersDf.as[User]
val airports = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(airports.as[Airport]) 

val output=  users.flatMap { user=>
    airports.value.flatMap { airport=>
        val dist = distance(airport.longitude,airport.lat,user.longitude,user.lat,1.0) //was not sure what R is 
        if(dist < 10.0) Seq((user.id,airport.id,dist))
        else Seq.empty
    }
  }
```

> Since there's no join how to get the output in the required format?

You can also define your custom class and populate the fields accordingly.

Although important to note: when you are using the spark dataset API, you miss out on some optimizations done by spark.

Comment: Basically were doing a nested loop. Is there any other way than broadcasting? I have used it in the past and wasn't very efficient. 
Also, how'd I find the closest in scala/spark way.

Comment: Broadcasting won't be your bottleneck you are broadcasting 150KB this is hardly anything.

You could join every row of user with every row in airport, but the number of rows will explode I expect the performance will be worse.

Comment: unless you are able to prefilter the airport data to your user data, you will always need to do 1M * 7000 calculations.

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped alot. and yes I also thought there's no other way than m*n maybe kd trees or something. 
I tried with Dataset but there were a lot of encoder errors and have to change to DF back again. So I just stuck with DF, the signatures looked cleaner, it worked fine. I updated the question, could you answer a few?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of computation related to geospacial area, it makes sense for you to take a look at [GeoSpark](https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/). It allows you easily get rid of UDFs and grouBy's burden. For instance, [finding K Nearest Neighbors](https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/tutorial/rdd/):

```
val geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory()
val pointObject = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(-84.01, 34.01))
val K = 1000 // K Nearest Neighbors
val usingIndex = false
val result = KNNQuery.SpatialKnnQuery(objectRDD, pointObject, K, usingIndex)
```

In your example you need just the nearest point, so put K=1 or try to find the method for returning the closest point (not sure whether it exists).
If you don't like using 3-rd party libs, just go with UDFs + groupby, or some Window functions.

**UPD**

1. Prefer using DF to UDFs due to performance. Tungsten can optimise operations with DF but not with UDFs.
2. Broadcasting here is fine.
3. imho, I don't like nested methods and mutation of variables, also
4. Spark is fine for this case, but your success also depends on cluster configuration and proper resource allocation for each task if it'd done as a batch app.

Comment: Thanks! i'll definitely try it! Also, I updated the question, could you answer a few?

Comment: @Sam check UPD section

Comment: Thanks! yes, I know about the configurations. 
one question tho. you mentioned UDF+group by or window function. why we need groupby or window function when all the ids are unique? Does it have to do something with partitioning data or sending a certain amount of records to executor?

Comment: @Sam you can use window functions instead of awkward foreach\flatMap, also use built-in window function instead of writing your own.